# Remove duplicates from two hash set

Tags: java, set, hashset

In my case i have two hash sets one set contain friend's name and number and another set 
contain existing friend's name and number this data retrieved from db and stored into set 
how to compare and removing duplicates from tow set and intersection data stored into new set?
i need code for that in google i saw the comparator in comparator they used only one set but in my case i am checking two sets sorry for my bad english

Comment: any codes you tried ?

Comment: Show some java. Declaration of hash maps/sets. Sample data. Expected result.

Comment: Friend f1=new Friend("Karthik","111");
Friend f2=new Friend("Mani","222");
Friend f3=new Friend("Karthik","111");
Friend f4=new Friend("Mani","Manik");
Friend f5=new Friend("Karthik","111");
Set<Friend> f=new HashSet<Friend>();
f.add(f1);
f.add(f2);
f.add(f3);
f.add(f4);
f.add(f5);
  
Set<Friend> set2=new HashSet<Friend>();
set2.add(new Friend("Karthik", "111"));
set2.add(new Friend("Raju", "3333"));

Comment: You need to implement equals and hashcode - correct?

Comment: correct.in equals method how to compare two set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming we have set1 and set2 we can do the following

```
    Set set3 = new HashSet(set1);
    set3.retainAll(set2);    
    set1.removeAll(set3);
    set2.removeAll(set3);
```

in your case this is

```
public class Friend {
    String name;
    String number;

    public Friend(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode() + 31 * number.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Friend)) {
            return false;
        }
        Friend other = (Friend)obj;
        return other.number.equals(number) && other.name.equals(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + "-" + number;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Set<Friend> set1 = new HashSet<Friend>();
    set1.add(new Friend("Karthik", "111"));
    set1.add(new Friend("Mani", "222"));
    set1.add(new Friend("Karthik", "111"));
    set1.add(new Friend("Mani", "444"));
    set1.add(new Friend("Karthik", "111"));

    Set<Friend> set2 = new HashSet<Friend>();
    set2.add(new Friend("Karthik", "111"));
    set2.add(new Friend("Raju", "3333"));

    Set<Friend> set3 = new HashSet<Friend>(set1);
    set3.retainAll(set2);
    set1.removeAll(set3);
    set2.removeAll(set3);

    System.out.println(set1);
    System.out.println(set2);
}
```

output

```
[Mani-444, Mani-222]
[Raju-3333]
```

Comment: hi my input is Set<Friend> set1=new HashSet<Friend>();
set1.add(new Friend("Karthik","111"));
set1.add(new Friend("Mani","222"));
set1.add(new Friend("Karthik","111"));
set1.add(new Friend("Mani","444"));
set1.add(new Friend("Karthik","111"));  
Set<Friend> set2=new HashSet<Friend>();
set2.add(new Friend("Karthik", "111"));
set2.add(new Friend("Raju", "3333"));        
Set<Friend> set3 = new HashSet<Friend>(set1)set3.retainAll(set2);    set1.removeAll(set3);set2.removeAll(set3); if i'm print set3 it display empty set.if i'm print set2 it display set2 data. which set have a non duplicate data?

Comment: thanks for reply.it's work fine.but i need check the number that is id also

Comment: private String name;private String number;//getter setter method@Override public int hashCode() {return name.hashCode()+number.hashCode();}@Override public boolean equals(Object obj){if (this == obj)return true;if (obj == null)return false;if (getClass() != obj.getClass())return false;Friend other = (Friend) obj;if (name == null) {if (other.name != null)return false;
} else if (!name.equals(other.name))return false;if (number == null) {if (other.number != null)return false;}else if(!number.equals(other.number))return false;return true;}

Comment: you are correct.but if i'm change the input for set2 isset2.add(new Friend("Karthikeyan", "111"));set2.add(new Friend("Raju", "3333")); it gives the output is Karthikeyan-111 ,Raju-3333.but i need raju-3333 only because the 111 number is already in set1.

Comment: well, then you should change hashCode and equals to care only for number

Comment: but in my case check both case.so i'm using 'or' condition for equals method but it is not working properly.Eg:return ((Friend)obj).name.equals(name)|| ((Friend)obj).number.equals(number);

Comment: then you shoud use HashMap and use number as key

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 Friend f1=new Friend("Karthik",111); 
 Friend f2=new Friend("Mani",222); 
 Friend f3=new Friend("Karthik",111); 
 Friend f4=new Friend("Mani",222); 
 Friend f5=new Friend("Karthik",111); 

 Set<Friend> set1=new HashSet<Friend>(); 
 set1.add(f1); 
 set1.add(f2); 
 set1.add(f3); 
 set1.add(f4); 
 set1.add(f5); 

 Set<Friend> set2=new HashSet<Friend>(); 
 set2.add(new Friend("Karthik", 111)); 
 set2.add(new Friend("Raju", 333));  
 set1.addAll(set2); //Adding all the objects from set2 to set1

 Set<Friend> set3=new HashSet<Friend>(); // creating a new Set object
/////////// Logic for removing duplicates ///////////////////////
 Set mine=new HashSet();
 for (Iterator<Friend> it = set1.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
 Friend s = it.next();
    if(mine.add(s.getName()))
    set3.add(new Friend(s.getName(),s.getId()));
 }
 /////////// Now set3 contains non-duplicates objects ///////////
 for (Iterator<Friend> it = set3.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
 Friend s = it.next();
     System.out.println("Name:"+s.getName()+"   Id:"+s.getId());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your requirement is that removing duplicates from two set and intersection data stored into new set.

My way is I override hashCode() and equals() method in Friend class.
Then I create commonFriends that have intersection data with [retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)() method like this.
**Modify - getting remaining data in both set**

```
Set<Friend> commonFriend = new HashSet<Friend>();
commonFriend.addAll(f);
commonFriend.retainAll(set2);
// Find remaining data
set2.removeAll(commonFriend);
f.removeAll(commonFriend);
```

Detail coding is

```
package examA;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Friend f1 = new Friend("Karthik", "111");
        Friend f2 = new Friend("Mani", "222");
        Friend f3 = new Friend("Karthik", "111");
        Friend f4 = new Friend("Mani", "Manik");
        Friend f5 = new Friend("Karthik", "111");

        Set<Friend> f = new HashSet<Friend>();
        f.add(f1);
        f.add(f2);
        f.add(f3);
        f.add(f4);
        f.add(f5);

        Set<Friend> set2 = new HashSet<Friend>();
        set2.add(new Friend("Karthik", "111"));
        set2.add(new Friend("Raju", "3333"));
        set2.add(new Friend("Karthikeyan", "111"));
        set2.add(new Friend("Raju", "3333"));

        System.out.println("Set 1 size" + f.size());
        System.out.println("Set 2 size" + set2.size());

        Set<Friend> commonFriend = new HashSet<Friend>();
        commonFriend.addAll(f);
        commonFriend.retainAll(set2);
        System.out.println("Common size" + commonFriend.size());

        f.removeAll(commonFriend);
        System.out.println("Remaining Data in f" + f.size());

        set2.removeAll(commonFriend);
        System.out.println("Remaining Data in set2" + set2.size());
        for (Friend friend : commonFriend) {
            System.out.println(friend);
        }
    }
}

class Friend {
    private String name;
    private String number;

    public Friend(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Friend [name=" + name + ", number=" + number + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((number == null) ? 0 : number.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Friend other = (Friend) obj;
        if (number == null) {
            if (other.number != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!number.equals(other.number))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for u'r reply.it's work fine.but it display only common data from two set.but i expect remaining data in set2 except common data after removing data.

Comment: I modify my code for getting remaining data in both set.. Hope u help!!

Comment: thanks for u'r reply.it is work fine.but but if i'm change the input for set2 isset2.add(new Friend("Karthikeyan", "111"));set2.add(new Friend("Raju", "3333")); it gives the output set2 is Karthikeyan-111 ,Raju-3333.but i need raju-3333 only because the 111 number is already in set1.but i need output of set2 is only Raju-3333

Comment: I get your point. You only want to check with number, not name. If so please revise hashCode and equal methods to make sure it use only number. I modify my detail code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> [addAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

method of set. This will copy elements from one set to other. And since Sets wont allow duplicates, it will be taken care